# Pegar mais de um elemento de um Array

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como pego 2 elementos de um array de uma vez.

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3]
let primeiros = numeros[1]
```

mas eu preciso pegar os 2 primeiros valores, e nao encontrei como fazer.
Preciso algo como:

```
let primeiros = numeros[1:2]
```

Comment: Entendo que não é o que você precisa agora, mas saber disso pode ajudar em alguma ocasião: `const [primeiro, segundo] = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
let numeros = [1, 2, 3];
let primeiros = numeros.slice(0, 2);
console.log(primeiros);
```

Os parâmetros representam, respectivamente, o primeiro índice que você quer, e o índices seguinte ao último desejado.

Comment: Uma possibilidade também descrita em outra resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547784/select-multiple-array-elements-javascript